# data.table group by function return multiple rows or list

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

Here is my data.table

```
res = structure(list(ID = c("0c980", "0c980", "0c980", "91320", "f3750", "1b970", "1b970", "1b970", "1b970"), 
                     datetime = structure(c(1547128003, 1549873907, 1550057899, 1544261100, 1550409081, 1547295708, 1561875112, 1562846678, 1564143917), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), 
                row.names = c(NA, -9L), 
                class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

the data are

```
      ID            datetime
1: 0c980 2019-01-10 21:46:43
2: 0c980 2019-02-11 16:31:47
3: 0c980 2019-02-13 19:38:19
4: 91320 2018-12-08 17:25:00
5: f3750 2019-02-17 21:11:21
6: 1b970 2019-01-12 20:21:48
7: 1b970 2019-06-30 14:11:52
8: 1b970 2019-07-11 20:04:38
9: 1b970 2019-07-26 20:25:17
```

I want to number each record based on the time interval between neighboring records within same IDs.

I create such function,

```
myFun = function(x,interval=7){
  if(length(x)==1){
    d = 1
  }else{
    a = difftime(x[-1],x[-length(x)],units = 'days')
    b = which(a>=interval)
    c = diff(c(0,b,length(x)))
    d = rep(x = seq(length(b)+1),time = c)
  }
  return(list(d))
}
```

the output is

```
> res[,.(myFun(datetime)),by=.(ID)]
      ID      V1
1: 0c980   1,2,2
2: 91320       1
3: f3750       1
4: 1b970 1,2,3,4
```

the output I want is

```
      ID            datetime V1
1: 0c980 2019-01-10 21:46:43 1
2: 0c980 2019-02-11 16:31:47 2
3: 0c980 2019-02-13 19:38:19 2
4: 91320 2018-12-08 17:25:00 1
5: f3750 2019-02-17 21:11:21 1
6: 1b970 2019-01-12 20:21:48 1
7: 1b970 2019-06-30 14:11:52 2
8: 1b970 2019-07-11 20:04:38 3
9: 1b970 2019-07-26 20:25:17 4
```

Could the data.table calculate by group and return multiple rows?

If data.table cannot, any other way to solve my question? tidyverse?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `list` column is having different `class` i.e. integer and numeric.  If we convert to same class, then `unlist`, and assign (`:=`), it can create a new column in the original data

```
res[, V1 := unlist(lapply(myFun(datetime), as.numeric)),by=.(ID)]
```